# Usercontrol changing position while scrolling in listview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am working on a win 8 app. I am using a user control in listview itemtemplate, problem is that when I scroll items usercontrol changes position means changes position in listview.

```
                                <userControl:DropDownUserControl/>
                                <Image x:Name="imgnote" Source="/Assets/notepad.png" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="15 0 0 0" Tapped="imgnote_Tapped"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Is there any way or problem.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're saying. Are you saying that when you want the contents of your UserControl to scroll, in fact the *parent* ListView is scrolling instead?

Comment: When I scroll my parent listview to the bottom and again upwards usercontrol just changes position, swap to other item of parent listview.

Comment: Ok, and what behaviour do you want to see?

Comment: That's my problem. I don't want it.

Comment: Do you want to disable scrolling altogether?

Comment: Not scrolling, I want to stop usercontrol movement.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your ListView XAML?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47334/discussion-between-mayank-karki-and-baldrick)